# Android google-play-services_lib - Resource never released

Tags: android, push-notification, google-api

I've to do an app that implement push notification. I've downloaded google-play-services_lib and import it in my project but, when i run the appm it give me this error:

> A resource was acquired at attached stack trace but never released. See java.io.Closeable for information on avoiding resource leaks.

Then it say:

> Unable to execute dex: overhead limit exceeded

I think that there is a problem with the lib (the import of it), because the code is really sample and i don't call any function of the library
How can i fix it?

Thi is the code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

public static final String EXTRA_MESSAGE = "message";
public static final String PROPERTY_REG_ID = "registration_id";
private static final String PROPERTY_APP_VERSION = "appVersion";
private static final int PLAY_SERVICES_RESOLUTION_REQUEST = 9000;
private Context context;

private String SENDER_ID = "xxxxxxxxxx";

/**
 * Tag used on log messages.
 */
private static final String TAG = "GCM Demo";


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    StrictMode.VmPolicy.Builder vmPolicyBuilder = new StrictMode.VmPolicy.Builder().detectAll().penaltyLog();
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
   context = this.getApplicationContext();
}



private void registerCloudMessaging() {
    GoogleCloudMessaging gcm = GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(context);

    // repeated calls to this method will return the same registration ID
    // a new registration is needed if the app is updated or backup & restore happens
    try {
        String registrationId = gcm.register(SENDER_ID);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    // then uploads the registration ID to your server

}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
}
}



public class BroadcastReceiver extends WakefulBroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    GoogleCloudMessaging gcm = GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(context);

    String messageType = gcm.getMessageType(intent);
    if (GoogleCloudMessaging.MESSAGE_TYPE_SEND_ERROR.equals(messageType)) {
        // error occurs
    } else if (GoogleCloudMessaging.MESSAGE_TYPE_DELETED.equals(messageType)) {
        // the server have deleted some pending messages,
        // because they are collapsible
    } else if (GoogleCloudMessaging.MESSAGE_TYPE_MESSAGE.equals(messageType)) {
        // normal message
        // how the data can be fetched is detailed in the next section
    }
}
}
```

And this is the manifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.provapush"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="14"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

   <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE"/>

    <permission
        android:name="com.example.provapush.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.example.provapush.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <!-- Required for applications which use Google Play Services. -->
       <meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
    android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />


        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>


        <receiver
            android:name=".BroadcastReceiver"
            android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
            <intent-filter>
                <!-- Receives the actual messages. -->
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
                <category android:name="com.example.provapush" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

I use as emulator a Google APIs level 18

Comment: What is the use of vmPolicyBuilder

Comment: i read in internet that if i add that line, it could work... don't work. So that line is useless

Comment: Try removing that line

Answer (score 0):

Above Code Work fine on my phone . Try running your code on a phone rather than on a emulator sometimes emulator does not work as expected.

You do not need to install google apis and play services on a phone and that might be creating some resource not closable on emulator.